# INSERT field of type TIME

Tags: c#, odbc, clarion

This question is for inserting data into Clarion .TPS files using the TopSpeed ODBC driver.  We are using C#.

I have an insert statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO MYTAB
(SOMEDATE, SOMETIME) VALUES ({d '2020-08-25'}, 1)
```

with SOMETIME being defined as TIME.

We get this error while trying to insert:

```
ERROR [S0000] [SoftVelocity Inc.][TopSpeed ODBC Driver]Invalid operand for operator: <assignment>
```

The vague error messages are really annoying.

What is the appropriate way to specify a time?

I am trying just an integer as that is what the documentation days a time is (100ths of seconds since midnight + 1).

Is there some definitive guide to the SQL syntax that is allowed with the softvelocity ODBC driver as it is a bit exhausting to be guessing.

Comment: Did you try a DateTime or a TimeSpan? A *time* is just a TimeSpan offset from midnight

Comment: @Flydog57 You may have missed the Clarion tag.   I will edit the question so others don't fall into the same trap.

Comment: No idea about this TopSpeed ODBC driver and I checked all over the internet and there is no documentation! But have you tried passing in the following time format instead: { t 'hh:mi:ss'} for example:   {t '23:40:00'}  ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and a few other variations.  We can read the field; it comes back as a integer.  Just can't figure out how to write it.

Comment: "We get an error while inserting." - You have sufficient rep and badges to know that is an insufficient description of the problem.

Comment: @GordThompson I got the error message from the developer and added it to the post.

Comment: *"The vague error messages are really annoying."* - Indeed, as are dodgy ODBC drivers. *"What is the appropriate way to specify a time?"* - As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/date-time-and-timestamp-escape-sequences?view=sql-server-ver15), `{t '19:20:21.23'}` should work, and a reasonably robust driver would also accept the string equivalent `'19:20:21.23'`. If neither of those works then you'll need to reach out to the driver provider and get them to tell you what (if anything) *will* work.